# クラスA, クラスB, クラスC というのはもう使われていないのですか？

Tags: network

質問としては表題のとおりです。

下記に初期は「クラス」が使われていたとあります。

[CIDR（クラスレスアドレッシング）とは - IT用語辞典 e-Words](http://e-words.jp/w/CIDR.html)

> インターネット普及の初期、IPアドレスは3段階の固定サイズの「クラス」に分類され、組織規模に応じて割り当てられていた。「クラスA」は上位8ビットがネットワーク部で残り24ビットがホスト部、「クラスB」はネットワーク部が16ビット、「クラスC」は24ビットである。
> しかし、AとB、BとCでそれぞれ256倍もアドレス数が異なり、クラスAは一つのブロックが1677万アドレスもあるため、インターネットの急激な普及により未割り当てアドレス領域が逼迫する一方、割り当て済みの組織ではアドレスを活用できずに大量に余らせてしまうという事態が生じた。
> そこで、CIDRでは1ビット単位で可変長の「サブネットマスク」（subnet mask）を用いてネットワーク部の大きさを指定するようにして、割り当てるブロックのサイズを柔軟に変更できるようにした。

下記はソニーがAクラスを取得したと聞いたという記述があります。

[IPアドレスのクラスAを取得している企業などについて -IPアドレスのク- その他（インターネット接続・インフラ） | 教えて!goo](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/68801.html)

> IPアドレスのクラスAって126種類あると思うのですが、最近日本の企業では唯一ソニーが取得していると聞きました。

## 質問

クラスA, クラスB, クラスC というのはもう使われていないのですか？
（持ってた企業、団体はIPアドレスを返したんでしょうか？）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

表記としてのクラスA, B, CはCIDR表記で/8, /16, /24と書き換えられ、特に/18や/21と区別する理由もありませんので、体感ではこちらを使用することがほとんどです。他の場所では使われているかもしれませんが…。

IPv4アドレスの枯渇はずっと言われていたことですから、CIDRの登場とは別に、[スタンフォード大などがIPアドレスを返還しています](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%89%B2%E3%82%8A%E5%BD%93%E3%81%A6%E6%B8%88%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AE/8%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%96%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7)。またクラスA規模のアドレス空間を所有していたMITも[その半分をAmazonに売却しました](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3191503/mit-selling-8-million-coveted-ipv4-addresses-amazon-a-buyer.html)。AT&Tなど、アドレス空間を持ち続けている組織もあるようです。

Comment: つまりまだ使われているということでしょうか？

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi ほぼ使われていませんが、ないとは言い切れません（他サイトでもこのような書き方ばかりでした）。少なくとも、クラスを知らなくて困る、という場面は今では考えにくいです。

Comment: @sei0oさん なるほど。なんだか難しそうな話ですね。言い切れない理由が気になります。